# Retrieve spatial points of raster brick

Tags: spatial, points

I'm trying to extract and plot some points on a raster. 
I did the following:

```
library(sp)
pt1 <- data.frame(cbind(4110000,40000))####almost completely degraded
pt2 <- data.frame(cbind(4100000,0))#####green
pt3 <-  data.frame(cbind(4140000,55000))####slightly green
pt <- rbind(pt1, pt2, pt3)
coordinates(pt) <- c("X1","X2")

points(pt)
```

But, the line:
    `coordinates(pt) <- c("X1","X2")`

is giving that error which is affecting the plotting:

Error in `coordinates<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("X1", "X2")) : 
  setting coordinates cannot be done on Spatial objects, where they have already been set.....

Any advice please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine. The error only happens when you run this row twice:

```
coordinates(pt) <- c("X1","X2")
```

To plot these on top of a raster `r`

```
plot(r)
points(pt)
```

Comment: Those are points to be extracted from raster, but i do not know how to plot them on the raster..